# How to get bash to automatically refresh program locations' cache?

Tags: linux, bash

I am aware of the bash internal command `hash` and how one can use `hash -d` or `hash -r` to forget remembered locations. Is there a way to instruct `bash` to automatically do this whenever it gets a "cache miss", i.e. when the remembered location goes away (`no such file or directory`) `bash` would clear the remembered location and try again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `checkhash` option:

```
shopt -s checkhash

checkhash
    If set, bash checks that a command found in the hash table exists
    before trying to execute it.  If  a  hashed  command  no longer
    exists, a normal path search is performed.
```

You can make that the option for all bash shells by putting it into the `BASHOPTS` environment variable:

```
BASHOPTS
    A colon-separated list of enabled shell options.
    Each word in the list is a valid argument for the
    -s option to the shopt builtin command.
```

Setting this option may slightly slow down bash execution, since almost all of the time, the extra test is unnecessary. However, I wouldn't think that the cost of the test is significant.

Comment: The cost of the test is relevant (each disk access == latency), but you are comparing that cost to the cost of searching the entire PATH for the file.  Seems cheap for providing the feature the requester wanted.

Comment: @slartibartfast: agreed. As I said, the cost is probably not significant.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. I wonder if there are Linux dists with this option set as the default?

Comment: @GerryLufwansa: I doubt it, but it hardly seems like a deciding feature for a selecting a distro. It's just one line to add to your bash startup file (although figuring out which file can be a challenge with some distributions).