# Multiple Installations and Understanding $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, path

I have an older version of Git installed at:

```
/usr/bin/
```

I recently downloaded a newer version to:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

When I type:

```
which git
```

I get the location of the old version. I believe that this is just because /usr/bin/ appears before /usr/local/bin in my $PATH variable and so the older version of git is 'found' first.

To test this, I renamed the older version of git to "git_old". Now when I type:

```
which git
```

I get the location of the newer version, as expected. But when I type:

```
git --version
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

I'm just wondering why my computer is going back to looking in the old location for Git?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bash caches the full path to executables so that it doesn't have to look through `$PATH` every time.

You can see what is in the cache using the `hash` command:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/git
```

This cache can be cleared with `hash -r`:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ hash -r
deltik@node51 [~]$ hash
hash: hash table empty
```

---

### Additional Resources

- [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5610) on Unix Stack Exchange
- [What is the purpose of the hash command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86017) on Unix Stack Exchange
- [How to get bash to automatically refresh program locations' cache?](https://superuser.com/a/734139/83694) on Super User
- [Documentation on `hash`](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160507040559/http://ss64.com/bash/hash.html)

Comment: wtf I never knew this, awesome.

Comment: Most other shells do the same thing, but they don't all use `hash -r` to reload the cache. Singer, such as SSH, use `rehash` as the command instead.

Comment: PATH=$PATH should clear the cache.  hash -r is not needed.