# After "make install" the executed binary is still the old one

Tags: linux, installation, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Sorry for my ignorance regarding Unix but I am puzzled about the behaviour of my Ubuntu (Windows subsystem). I built `GNU make` from source (because the current version in the repository is still at 4.1 which is from 2014 and buggy) and ran `sudo make install` as last step. The script ran through without problems and in the following you can see the last few actions of the install procedure, correctly copying `make` from my `install` to `/usr/local/bin/make`. The `which` command was also of the opinion that I was using `/usr/local/bin/make` but invoking make still gave me version `4.1` as you can see. Using the full path did the right thing, starting version `4.3`. How can this happen? I have knowledge from the stone age that Unix used to employ a file system cache or buffer but I thought this was a transparent thing? Where was `make V4.1` buffered in my system? 
When I opened a new shell, the behaviour was gone, now correctly using `4.3` when starting `make`. I know this from the command shell in Windows but can't draw a meaningful connection to the Linux subsystem.

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/user1/install/make-4.3'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c make '/usr/local/bin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/gnumake.h '/usr/local/include'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/make.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/install/make-4.3'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user1/install/make-4.3'
user1@dogbert:~/install/make-4.3$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
user1@dogbert:~/install/make-4.3$ which make
/usr/local/bin/make
user1@dogbert:~/install/make-4.3$ ./make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
user1@dogbert:~/install/make-4.3$ /usr/local/bin/make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: What shell? See [this](https://superuser.com/a/1104919/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yep this explains it. Before there existed `4.3` in `/usr/bin/local` there was `4.1` in `/usr/bin` and the cache is still pointing there. `which` and `bash` are having a different opinion. You can answer and I'll accept if you want.