# Git not executed from first location in $PATH

Tags: bash, git, macos

I seem to have two different instances of git installed on my Mac, and for some reason bash does not pick the one I'd like to use, even though its directory comes before the other instance's directory in the PATH variable.

Git is found in the following two directories

```
/usr/bin/git #git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128), probably installed by XCode
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.29.2/bin/git #installed by homebrew
```

There is also a symlink to the latter from /usr/local/bin/git

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 fredrik  admin  28 Dec  6 13:50 /usr/local/bin/git -> ../Cellar/git/2.29.2/bin/git
```

I would like to use the homebrew version, which is up to date (and easily kept so) while the XCode instance is an older one, which I was not able to easily update. However, for some reason, bash keeeps picking git from /usr/bin

```
fredrik ~ $ whereis git
/usr/bin/git
```

even though /usr/local/bin comes before /usr/bin in my PATH variable

```
fredrik ~ $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:~/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin
```

Why is this, and what should I do to get bash to pick the desired instance? I already tried to remove the git instance from /usr/bin but the system won't let me

```
fredrik bin $ rm -rf git
rm: git: Operation not permitted
```

probably due to System Integrity Protection or something.

Comment: How about `sudo rm /usr/bin/git` ?

Comment: However, I think that would be a little extreme.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1104919/432690

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Even ````sudo rm /usr/bin/git```` yields ````Operation not permitted````. No changes to ````/usr/bin```` seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You probably *are* using `/usr/local/bin/git`. The problem would be that you are not asking the right question. Don't use `whereis` (it doesn't do what you think it does); use `which`, like this:

```
which -a git
```

This will list all known `git` tools, in $PATH order. Or you could say simply

```
git --version
```

That will tell you what version a typical `git` command is using.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite sure what happened but now when I check again, it's indeed ````/usr/local/bin/git```` that gets executed, as one would have expected. I could swear this was not the case when I got prompted to post this issue, but who knows, maybe the fault was all the time located between the keyboard and the backrest. 

Comment: If my answer is correct, please accept it to close out this question-and-answer.